# Is it possible to pass a undefined method call as parameter?

Tags: delphi

I would like to build a wrapper function to extract data from a JSON a pass it to method. something like this

```
procedure THandler.MethodA(A,B:String)
begin
...
end;

procedure THandler.MethodB(A:String;B:Integer)
begin
...
end;

procedure THandler.MethodC(A,B,C:Integer)
begin
...
end;

procedure THandler.HandleCall(Data:tJSONObject;Handler:TUndefinedProc;Params:TArray<string>)
begin
 //read fields contained in "Params" from Data and pass them as variables to "Handler"
end

procedure THandler.CallA(Data:TJSONObject);
begin
 HandleCall(Data,MethodA,['param1','param2']);
end;
```

I see two challenges for now: How to pass the method to `HandleCall` and how to handle an undefined number of params inside of `HandleCall`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.  You can declare a type as a function or procedure template (it's how event handlers are defined).  You can also specify an array of arguments to allow passing a variable number of parameters (of the same type).  Or of course you can declare different types with different parameters.

You don't need to use `Rtti` to do this, but as an aside the `Rtti` unit uses this with the `Rtti` type `TValue` (which can hold multiple data types) to provide wrappers that allow Rtti to be used to discover and call anything you have declared.

Have you tried:

```
  type
  TMultiStringCallback = procedure(const args: TArray<String>) of object;
  TMultiIntCallback = procedure(const args: TArray<int>) of object;
```

Then if you have an object that includes such a function you want to invoke:

```
  TMyUsefulObject = class(TObject)
  protected
    procedure UsefulCallback(const args: TArray<String>); virtual;
    // ... etc
  end;
```

And a handler that accepts such a callback:

```
  TMyUsefulHandler = class(TObject)
  protected
    _fnCallback:    TMultiStringCallback;
  public
    property  OnCallback: TMultiStringCallback read _fnCallback write _fnCallback;
  end;
```

You can install the callback by passing the address of it like this:

```
procedure TMyUSefulObject.InstallcallbakInHanlder(AHandler: TMyUsefulHandler);
begin
  AHandler.OnCallback=Self.UsefulCallback;
end;
```

And the handler can invoke it like this:

```
procedure TMyUsefulHandler.InvokeCallback(const args: TArray<String>);
begin
  if(Assigned(Self._fnCallback)) then
    Self._fnCallback(args);
end;
```